# Cadastro senha com Hash no banco Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Oie galera não estou conseguindo cadastrar a senha com o hash no banco, consigo cadastrar todos os dados mas a senha não fica criptografada

```
public function CadastroSalvar (Request $request) {

   \App\Usuario::create($request->all(),[
       $request = Input::get('nome'),
       $request = Input::get('email'),
       $request = Input::get(Hash::make('senha')),
       $request = Input::get('telefone'),
       $request = Input::get('data_nascimento'),
       $request = Input::get('rg'),
       $request = Input::get('funcao'),
   ])->save();    


    return redirect()->route('UsuarioCadastro');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu código está errado e tem chamadas inválidas:

Quando se utiliza create, é requirido um `array` com as informações que são configurados no `$fillable` desse `model` e também para gerar a `hash` da senha estava utilizando o código invertido, exemplo do que seria o correto:

```
public function CadastroSalvar (Request $request) 
{

   $data = $request->all();
   $data['senha'] = \Hash::make($data['senha']); // ou bcrypt($data['senha']);

   $usuario = \App\Usuario::create($data);

   return redirect()->route('UsuarioCadastro');

}
```

***Referencias:***

- [Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing)
- [Insert, Update, Delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete)
- [Request::all() -> array all()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_all)

Comment: vlw man, Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela dica ^^